# Center box element with CSS

Tags: css

I try to center a box element since I reduced its max width to 1060px

[image]

URL: https://www.tresor-ethnique.com/cart

```
.ls-recommendation-box[data-box-type="Upsell"] .ls-ul li.ls-show {
    align-self: center !important;
}
```

Maybe the selector I chose is wrong? I tried couple of those

Any help would be greatly appreciated,
Let me know thanks :)
Pascal

Comment: Are you using flexbox?? if not then `align-self` definitely wont work, what you want to do is make sure it's a block element, and then just do `margin: 0 auto` and that will center it on the page

Comment: oh ok thank you! :)

Comment: Be very, very, careful using `!important` : https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/11/the-important-css-declaration-how-and-when-to-use-it/#when-should-important-be-used

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead

```
.ls-recommendation-box[data-box-type="Upsell"] .ls-ul li.ls-show {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

`justify-self: center` would only work if you were using flexbox

Comment: Great if this gave you the desired result, you can mark this answer as correct. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You only need to add **margin:0  auto** in your css

**Sample code**

```
.ls-recommendation-box[data-box-type="Upsell"] {
   margin: 0 auto !important; 
}
```

**Screenshot**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use flexbox for centering the content

```css
.main{
  display:flex;
  border:2px solid #333;
  justify-content:center;
  }
  .main01{
  width:60%;
  margin:20px auto;
  border:2px solid #333;
  text-align:center
  
  }
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <h2>Lorem</h2>
</div>

<div class="main01">
  <h2>Lorem</h2>
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt=""/>
</div>
```